# Checkbox cell in tableview on JavaFX

Tags: checkbox, javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm try create checkbox cell in tableview using FXML. Checkbox appear but not active. Clicking on it does not change its state. 
This is my FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import sample.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?scenebuilder-preview-i18n-resource BasicApplication_en.properties?>
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.file">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.new" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.open" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.open.recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.save.as" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.preferences" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.quit" onAction="#closeApp"/>
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.select.all" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.unselect.all" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="%menu.title.about" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <ToolBar>
      <items>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="%toolbar.button.add" />
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="%toolbar.button.edit" />
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="%toolbar.button.duplicate"     onAction="#duplicateAction"/>
      </items>
    </ToolBar>
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" >
          <columns>
              <TableColumn fx:id="enabledColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="%tableview.enabled">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="enabled" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
                  <cellFactory>
                      <CheckBoxCellFactory>
                      </CheckBoxCellFactory>
                  </cellFactory>
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="timeColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="%tableview.time">
              </TableColumn>
              <TableColumn fx:id="descriptionColumn" prefWidth="75.0"     text="%tableview.description">
                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="description" />
                  </cellValueFactory>
                  <cellFactory>
                      <FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="left">
                      </FormattedTableCellFactory>
                  </cellFactory>
              </TableColumn>
          </columns>
          <items>
              <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                  <MyTimer enabled="false" description="desc1"/>
                  <MyTimer enabled="true" description="desc2"/>
              </FXCollections>
          </items>
      </TableView>
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@BasicApplication.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</VBox>
```

and this is my CheckBoxCellFactory.java

```
package sample;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.util.Callback;
public class CheckBoxCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {
    @Override
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> p) {
        CheckBoxTableCell<S, T> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<S, T>(){
            private ObservableValue<T> ov;
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {

                super.updateItem((T) item, empty);
                if (item == null) {
                    super.setText(null);
                    super.setGraphic(null);
                }
                else {
                    if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {
                            super.selectedStateCallbackProperty().unbindBidirectional((ObjectProperty) ov);
                    }
                    ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
                    if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {
                            super.selectedStateCallbackProperty().bindBidirectional((ObjectProperty) ov);
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestCase extends RecursiveTreeObject<TestCase> {

// SimpleBooleanProperty
private SimpleBooleanProperty isSelected;}

TreeTableColumn<TestCase, Boolean> selectColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Select");


    selectColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(selectColumn));
    selectColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
        return param.getValue().getValue().getIsSelected();
    });

    selectColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<TestCase, Boolean> t) -> {
        ((TestCase) t.getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(t.getTreeTablePosition().getRow()).getValue()).getIsSelected()
                .set(t.getNewValue());
        // refreshTable(t);
    });


    `
```